# onClick HOME key display alert box in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-homebutton

I am sincerely trying to display `alert box` onClick of `Home key`, but I am not succeeded. So please help me to write the code otherwise, show me the code.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) 
  {
      finish();
    return false;
  }
  else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)
  {
      finish();
    return false;
  }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

Comment: can you share the solution of display alert box onClick of Home key.

Answer (score 2):

it is not possible to intercept KEYCODE_HOME by external applications:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1979

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can intercept HOME key presses. It is reserved to ensure that you don't get locked within any application.

`KEYCODE_HOME` : This key is handled by the frame work and is never delivered to applications.
So you can't use it